# Javascript - Detect Headset Button Pressed

Tags: javascript, keycode, headset

I am wondering if it's possible to detect if the button on a headset plugged into a PC is pressed in JavaScript or any other language that works on a website?

I understand that you can use key code e.g. 32 to detect a keyboard button being pressed however there doesn't seem to be one for a headset button.

Comment: Probably not, but that probably depends on any number of things?

Comment: Are you referring to a microphone headset, or a User Interface headset?

Comment: Well I know it works on mobile because you can use it on the spotify website. So maybe there is a way to do it on mobile in JavaScript?

Comment: @Xarus I mean a headset like a pair of earbuds with a button on it used to pause/play music.

Comment: Have you tried simply creating an event handler for keypress and/or keydown/keyup and checking whether or not the headset button actually triggers anything?

Comment: `pause/play` just check if audio is paused.